# Where is the declaration of execution of ecryptfs for on user login automount?

Tags: ecryptfs

1. For a `~/Private` mount generated by the ecryptfs helper utility, where is the declaration to execute ecryptfs on user login?
2. Same question but for an encrypted Home, as in that case it presumably wouldn't be in anything related to `.profile`.

I'm not talking about the automount file, I'm talking about something like an upstart service listening for user login, or something executed with the same convention as `~/.profile` (on login shell)?

Answer (score 1):

Setting up the Private on Ubuntu utilizes:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man8/pam_ecryptfs.8.html

to modify the pam stack. However, it differs from the man page on
at least 12.04.3:

`auth    optional        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap`

In common-auth as opposed to:

`auth    required        pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap`